# Identical https request gets different response in browser and cURL/Node.js

Tags: web-scraping, curl, captcha, cloudflare

I'm trying to scrape some data from a web page that allows data scraping in their `robots.txt` file.
In order to get the data that I want, I looked into API requests that the web page sends when loading and I identified the API requests of interest.

If I copy the request URL as seen in `Brave -> Network` tab and paste it into new tab, I get the JSON data identical to the one that the web page gets when loading. However, if I copy that request as `cURL` command, with the same headers, cookies etc., and execute it in my terminal, I get a Cloudflare `html` page that mentions `captcha-bypass` and has "Checking your browser..." message.

I tried exporting cookies from my browser to a file and then using them with `cURL` but it doesn't work. I also tried comparing HTTP requests sent at different times, in case something like a timestamp gets added to the request, but they are the same. And one more thing: when sending the API request from the browser, I don't get any Captcha challenges to solve, I just get the JSON back.

I would like to know the mechanism by which the server determines that I'm not using a browser just from the HTTP request.

**UPDATE**: I tried sending request with Tor and in this case I get back the same page as in `cURL` request. After some time, the Captcha gets verified on its own and the `JSON` data gets loaded as in a regular browser.

Comment: did you copy all headers? Did you copy `User-Agent`? CloudFlare may also use `JavaScript` to detect script/bot - and `curl` can't run `JavaScript`

Comment: I used `Copy as cURL` functionality from the browser which should create an identical cURL command, including `User-Agent` and everything else.

Comment: probably it uses JavaScript for this. You may also turn off JavaScript in browser and load url to see if you can get it without JavaScript.

Comment: Turning off JavaScript inside the browser doesn't change anything, I still get the data from API.

Comment: so it has more complex system to detect script. or it didn't generate curl command which doesn't work exactly like browser.

Comment: with Python you could try module [cloudscraper](https://github.com/VeNoMouS/cloudscraper) to bypass Cloudflare's anti-bot page but it seems module uses some JavaScript engine for this.

Comment: @furas I tried using `cloudflare-scraper` from `npm` and it got the same `html` as with the `cURL` request. I also tried using `cloudscraper` with the same response. Also, I updated the question with the new stuff that I tried, perhaps it sheds some light on the problem.

Comment: I've had _some_ success with Puppeter and Selenium before. It uses real browser for it. Check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments suggested, the reason why `cURL` didn't show the same output is that the server would first serve a html page where some javascript code gets automatically executed. After the code is executed, the actual data gets requested and shown.

I'm not sure why this can't be seen in the `Network` tab in dev tools nor is it indicated anywhere in the browser while the response is being fetched.

I figured it out by trying to send the api request via Tor. That's the only browser which showed that something was going on before sending the redirect request.

In the end I automated this with `puppeteer`, as suggested by [skyez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3209381/sykez).